# Python - Converting Binary (list) to Decimal

Tags: python, math, binary

I've been trying to write a code to convert a Binary list to decimal, for example:

```
[1,1,0,1]
```

The code I've written so far is as follows:

```
def binatodeci(binary):
    binary = []
    decimal = 0 
    binary.reverse()
    for i in range(len(binary)):
        decimal = decimal + (2**i)*binary[i]
    return decimal
```

However every time I try to use this function it returns 0. Why is this the case? I can't seem to spot the error in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, simply remove this line as you are immediately reassigning over the functions input argument

```
binary = []
```

As a more concise alternative

```
def binatodeci(binary):
    return sum(val*(2**idx) for idx, val in enumerate(reversed(binary)))
```

Example

```
>>> binatodeci([1,1,0,1])
13
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [Cory Kramer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64391584/3080723), simply remove the line `binary = []` at the beginning of your code and it will work perfectly.

Here is an alternative algorithm, given as food for thought:

```py
def binatointeger(binary):
  number = 0
  for b in binary:
    number = (2 * number) + b
  return number
```

### Important note

Note that the resulting number is **not** in decimal. It's a python integer. Internally in the computer, python integers are stored in binary. The conversion to decimal representation, i.e., to a string of digits, happens when calling the function `print`, `str`, or `repr`, to print the number to screen.